# pointers with numbers in backwards

Tags: c++, pointers

I need to receive an undetermined number of integer numbers in between (0-9). With this numbers, print them forwards and backwards, and then erase the numbers at the corners.

Example:

```
3 5 1 9 4 6 2 4 4 2 6 4 9 1 5 3 
  5 1 9 4 6 2 4 4 2 6 4 9 1 5 
    1 9 4 6 2 4 4 2 6 4 9 1 
      9 4 6 2 4 4 2 6 4 9 
        4 6 2 4 4 2 6 4 
          6 2 4 4 2 6 
            2 4 4 2 
              4 4
```

And here is the code I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int a;
int p;
int set;

void numberss()
{
    for set[](int a=0; a<p; a++) 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    cin >> p;
    cin >> a;
    const int SIZE = p;
    int set[] = {a};
    int *numPtr;
    numPtr = set;
    for (int index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
    {
        cout << *numPtr << " ";
        numPtr++;
    }

    for (int index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
    {
        numPtr--;
        cout << *numPtr << " "; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have example code? What have you tried so far? Welcome to StackOverflow :)

Comment: [I downvoted because it seems like you haven't attempted this yourself.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) Please see the guides on how to pose a good question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on StackOverflow and people may be more inclined to offer support. We're not here to do the work for you, we're here to offer assistance when all other options are gone. That means once you've researched, once you've tried to code it, once it's been debugged to the best of your ability and then some. - Edit. Not trying to discourage you, just trying to help you get this answered. :)

Comment: I've tried so far to put the numbers backwards, but it seem so complicated to first of all to delimit the number of number to be used in the array. I have done this so far. Please help.

Comment: #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int a;
int p;
int set;
void numberss()
{
  for set[](int a=0; a<p; a++)
}



int main()
{
  cin>>p;
  cin>>a;

    const int SIZE = p;
    int set[] = {a};
    int *numPtr;

    numPtr = set;

  
    
    for (int index = 0; index < SIZE; index++) {
        cout << *numPtr << " ";
        numPtr++;
    }

    
    
    for (int index = 0; index < SIZE; index++) {
        numPtr--;
        cout << *numPtr << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}

Comment: Please refer to @davedwards' comment on the subject. Please post a snippet of the code you're trying to write INTO your question through an edit. You can copy+paste it into your question, and then click the 'Code Format' button.

Comment: I went ahead and made an edit to your question to include the code in a formatted manner. Looks like it wont compile, though, as you're trying to call a for loop in a variable using incorrect syntax in your `numberss` function.

Comment: @JamesWhyte  please help, its for a CC project.

Comment: It's highly recommended you attempt this yourself; it is a learning project after all. I'm more than happy to give you an example of how I would go about it, but I reiterate that this problem and you overcoming it will make you a better programmer.

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer below as the correct answer so that people in the future can quickly find the answer that helped you the most. There are plenty of answers now, so have fun with the pot-luck! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we ignore errors, you can read the numbers in one at a time, and form a string for the first line of output. Forming the string will involve appending a reversed copy to the original. Once the string is formed, you can output that string for the first line. Then replace the first number with a space character, and shrink the string from the back by two characters. Keep doing that until you are done.

This works because the numbers are all single digit.

```
int main (void)
{
    int N;
    std::string nums;
    std::cin >> N;
    for (int i = 0, x; i < N; ++i) {
        std::cin >> x;
        nums += std::to_string(x) + ' ';
    }
    nums.append(nums.rbegin() + 1, nums.rend());
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        std::cout << nums << '\n';
        nums[2*i] = ' ';
        nums.resize(nums.size()-2);
     }
}
```

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](https://tio.run/##fY7BboMwEETvfMVIPWCXJGpocwmET8gPtFFEjYtWCjYyJkKJ8u3Uxg1qq6q@eLQzO/tE2y5rIcYHUuLUVxI56c4aWTbFSMqiKUmBnTVVPLpGcM9P99kkO1ttty5Nqobqm@7bVLi1orgHP7QB84uEHZ4WGDKncuciSYgjFP/eHbJ57MuR7IJt9THcZANHghhxCN6ie3RVtq1UFZu0eZc1Keaj60WwjTc5/4vtfzDdW@R5wHF//Kbin5Cv6SMdXM8MNSMZ2dFFBqRJ8WX6ReDIb@O4idZI8YwXbD4B)

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because you are not reading all of the numbers from the user's input, you are only reading the count and the 1st number.  Also, you are not looping enough times to output the numbers in a triangular fashion, you are only outputting the 1st line of the triangle.

Try this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{ 
    int p;
    vector<int> set;

    cin >> p;
    set.resize(p);

    for (int i = 0; i < p; ++i)
        cin >> set[i];

    for (int index = 0; index < p; index++)
    {
        int *numPtr = &set[index];

        for (int i = 0; i < index; ++i)
            cout << "  ";           

        for (int i = index; i < p; ++i)
            cout << *numPtr++ << " ";

        for (int i = index; i < p; i++)
            cout << *--numPtr << " "; 

        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/8goQnd)

---

That being said, here is an alternative approach that is more C++-ish and less C-ish, by using iterators instead of pointers, and using STL algorithms.  Also, you should always validate user input before using it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstdint>

using uint16vec = std::vector<uint16_t>; // there is no operator>> for uint8_t...

int main()
{
    size_t count = 0;
    std::cin >> count;

    uint16vec set;
    set.reserve(count);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        uint16vec::value_type num;
        while (!((std::cin >> num) && (num <= 9)))
        {
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cout << "Enter a valid number 0..9!" << std::endl;
        }
        set.push_back(num);
    }

    auto begin = set.begin(), end = set.end();
    auto rbegin = set.rbegin(), rend = set.rend();
    auto out = std::ostream_iterator<uint16vec::value_type>(std::cout, " ");

    std::cout << std::setfill(' ');

    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << std::setw((i*2)+1);
        std::copy(begin++, end, out);
        std::copy(rbegin, rend--, out);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/O283AH)

Comment: I think the code works properly, but I use (using namespace std;) So I don't get the code that well.

Comment: I updated my answer to show a fixed version of your original code, which is broken

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot, mate. I've commented it so you can follow along. It allows for characters other than numbers because that seemingly wasn't a requirement of your assignment, so it's on you to sort and filter those out. It prints as intended, so here's hoping that this is what you're looking for to start off with your search for the right answer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void pop_front(vector<char>& _vector)
{
    _vector.front() = move(_vector.back());
    _vector.pop_back();
}

int main() 
{ 
    vector<char> characterList;
    string consoleInput;

    cin >> consoleInput;

    //Initialize by pushing everyting from the console into our vector.
    for (char c : consoleInput)
    {
        characterList.push_back(c);

    }

    //After adding from the console, now we'll do it in reverse.
    for (int i = consoleInput.length() - 1; i > -1; i--)
    {
        characterList.push_back(consoleInput[i]);
    }

    //Print where we are currently up to for display purposes.
    for (char c : characterList)
    {
        cout << c;
    }

    // Newline.
    cout << "\n";

    //Now let's start to chop it down. It'll take the same iterations as the console input, because we're doubling down.
    for (int i = 0; i < consoleInput.length() - 1; i++)
    {
        characterList.erase(characterList.begin());
        characterList.pop_back();

        for (char c : characterList)
        {
            cout << c;
        }

        cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```